# Kapacitor: Getting error while defining tick file

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, kapacitor

I'm on my very first script with kapacitor. I've written a tick file. Following is the script.

```
stream
        .from().measurement('cpu')
                .where("cpu" == 'cpu-total')
        .alert()
                .info(lamda:TRUE)
                .log('/tmp/cpu.log')
```

I'm defining tick file to kapacitor using following command

```
kapacitor define highcpu -type stream -dbrp telegraf.default -tick cpu.tick
```

Getting Following error

```
invalid TICKscript: parser: unexpected unknown state, last char: ':' line 5 char 14 in "info(lamda:TRUE)". expected: ")"
```

I'm not getting exactly going wrong. I'm sure there is nothing wrong with config and telegraf and influxdb.

Kapacitor version 1.3.1
OS: Fedora 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing 'b' in lamda.
Should be:     lambda.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** I'm not getting exactly going wrong.

**A:** Short answer, syntax error.

Unfortunately the parser for Kapacitor's `TICK` script is not that mature yet and you really can't blame them for it. This project is still a baby, hence these such of errors only appear during runtime.

The problem is with your lambda expression `.info(lamda:TRUE)`. You need to tell the expression which `field` or `tag` to lookup its value.

A typical `lambda` expression looks like

1. `info(lambda: if ("sum" >= 45000, '1', '0'))`
2. `info(lambda: "isPeakHour" == 'true')`

Something to note here is that, there is no `True` or `False` in Kapacitor yet. `1` or `0` is typically used to represent boolean.

You might also want to take note of `single quote` and `double quotes` in TICK script.

- Single quotes are string literals
- Double quotes are references to a field or tag. Double quotes are
  only used in lambda expressions.